# scikit-learn: Using SimpleImputer in Pipeline before MultilayerPerceptron

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm creating a data pipeline using scikit learns pipeline. My goal is to add a SimpleImputer to change all the NaN values to the most frequent values using the `'most-frequent'` strategy. Whenever I run it, I get the Following Value Error:

`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

I'm using a Jupyter notebook that is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

all_data = pd.read_csv('hospitals_by_county.csv')

# Homemade test, train split function. Returns 2 pandas dataframe subsets of the original.
(train, test) = data_splitter(all_data)

X_train = train
y_train = train['icu_available_beds']

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('scalar', StandardScaler())
])

numeric_features = all_data.select_dtypes(
    include=['int64', 'float64']).columns

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features)
    ])

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

rf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                    ('classifier', MLPClassifier())])


# Error occurs here.
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The full error message is coming from the MLPClassfier, but it to me it seems to indicate that the issue is that there are still NaN values in the data which should not be the case.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-168a6fc83696> in <module>
----> 1 rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    352                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    353             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
--> 354                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    355         return self
    356 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py in fit(self, X, y)
    993         """
    994         return self._fit(X, y, incremental=(self.warm_start and
--> 995                                             hasattr(self, "classes_")))
    996 
    997     @property

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py in _fit(self, X, y, incremental)
    323                              hidden_layer_sizes)
    324 
--> 325         X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental)
    326         n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    327 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py in _validate_input(self, X, y, incremental)
    930     def _validate_input(self, X, y, incremental):
    931         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
--> 932                          multi_output=True)
    933         if y.ndim == 2 and y.shape[1] == 1:
    934             y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    756     if multi_output:
    757         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,
--> 758                         dtype=None)
    759     else:
    760         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    576         if force_all_finite:
    577             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 578                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    579 
    580     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
     58                     msg_err.format
     59                     (type_err,
---> 60                      msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype)
     61             )
     62     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: Can you check if this answer helps? The input data might contain `inf` values that the SimpleImputer couldn't use imputation on.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364623/i-try-imputing-in-sklearn-but-i-have-an-
error/63370234#63370234

Comment: @PavithranRamachandran Thanks! I iterated over the entire data frame and there were no infinite values. I'm glad I checked though.